# Batch file that copy file to location in different SO

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup

I need to make firefox opens on startup with a specific page, thats the easy part but the problem is that i need to do it on many computers, some in PT and some in English and also some of them are win xp, win 7 , win vista and win 8.

Can i create a batch file that copy the startup.bat file to startup page of specific user that is running it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question right. It doesn't matter on which system language you are, you can alwasy use the `%PROGRAMFILES%` variable. The only difference is when you don't know whether your system is 32 or 64 bit. On a 32 bit system firefox can be found at `%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`. On a 64 bit system it's `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`. So you have to check the type of system and run firefox from the correct location. To do so you can check the `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` system variable:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==x86 (
    "%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe www.stackoverflow.com"
) ESLE (
    "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe /www.stackoverflow.com"
)
```

This script should work for any language and any Windows architecture.

Comment: Great thanks, but how about the place where the startup folder is, is there a way to do something like this to choose the correct path to copy the file? @MichaelS

Comment: If you are on > WinXP it's `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. On WinXP it's `%AllUsersProfile%\Start Menu\Startup` for all users and `%UserProfile%\Start Menu\Startup` for current user. Not completely sure about XP.

Comment: im thinking in doing this    copy "C:\startAT.bat" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\startAT.bat" 
copy "C:\startAT.bat" "C:\Documents and Settings\All users\Menu Iniciar\Programas\Inicializar\startAT.bat" 
copy "C:\startAT.bat" "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\startAT.bat"  if location dont exist it will give error and move to the next one right?